# How to put <a href on that like which is 3? I'm using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

How to put an anchor tag `<a href` on that number `3` using javascript? Below is my source code:

```
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
    var voteCount = $(this).siblings('.vote_count');
    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');      
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $.get("{{ URL::route('unvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
            console.log(data);
            voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
        });
    } else {

        if( $(this).hasClass('upvote')){
            $.get("{{ URL::route('upvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done(function(data){
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        } else {
            $.get("{{ URL::route('downvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Below is image for reference, here under the price tag I want to put anchor tag:

[image]

Here's my view code:

```
if(Auth::check()) { 
    echo ' <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:80px" > <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="hehehe"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span> </a> '; } echo   '<span class="vote_count"></span>'; if(Auth::check()) { echo    '<a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="#"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span> </a> </div>'; 
}
```

Comment: You must tag the framework that are you using to render that view, as well show the result of it, the html rendered.

Comment: @Don'tVotemeDown here's my view if(Auth::check()) {
echo '
<div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:80px" > 
<a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="hehehe">
              <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
</a> ';
 }  
echo '<span class="vote_count"></span>';
if(Auth::check()) {
           echo '<a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
 </a>
</div> 
 ';
}

Comment: Add to your question post, don't post information in the comments

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I'm sorry can't be addedna to my post naaah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *number 3* in your view is probably being rendered inside the following element:

```
<span class="vote_count"></span>
```

So why won't you wrap an `a` element around it?

```
<a href=''><span class="vote_count"></span></a>
```

Or you can do it dinamically with jQuery using [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$(".vote_count").wrap("<a href=''></a>");
```

Comment: @Don'tVoteMeDown Thank you so much. It works... Let me ask another question sir. Why is that when I press f5 which is refresh the number 3 will be gone? How to put it stay as is...

Comment: My question is how to get the number 3 stay steady even if you refresh it. @Don'tVoteMeDown

Comment: @jamo I think you may have that information in a database, right? You have to print it with the span at the render time.

Comment: yes yes. Where can I possible put that span thingy?

Comment: @jamo Well, when you print it: `'<span class="vote_count">' . $vote_count . '</span>';` or whatever is your vote count number...

Comment: @jamo its an example, you need to set your own variable, with the database count.